# Browse and Submit to webform using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a webpage, which has a textbox and a Browse and Submit button. Is there a way where using PowerShell I can select a file and submit to the webpage?

Comment: You need to work out if you can submit the file via a web API or a simple post. Can you capture the HTTP POST action when you submit the file? Is there any authentication required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click the `Submit` button on a site, the web browser performs an `HTTP Post` request.

PowerShell can perform `HTTP Post` request too, natively.  Chrome and Edge also let you capture any request and convert it into PowerShell syntax.  This can help you do what you want to do!  Here's the steps you'll follow:

1. Open Chrome
2. Go to the website in question
3. Hit F12 to open the developer tools
4. Go to the network tab
5. Click 'Preserve Log'
6. Perform your action as you normally would to browse to a file and then click submit.
7. You will see a new item appear in the Network tab in Chrome Devtools
8. You can right-click and 'Copy as PowerShell' to extract the HTTP Request operation and modify it to suit your needs.

For example, Berkley has a PHP Upload example page from 1996 which is still online and still works!  Let's use that to show these steps:

- Browse to this site: http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html
- Open dev tools and check 'Preserve Log'
  [image]
- Use the site as I normally do then click Submit...
  [image]
- Right click and extract the completed PowerShell command by right-clicking the request -> Copy - > Copy as PowerShell
  [image]

Now I can use this as the basis of a script!  Here's the PowerShell equivalent web request.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.cgi" `
-Method "POST" `
-Headers @{
"Cache-Control"="max-age=0"
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"="1"
  "Origin"="http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu"
  "User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4170.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.552.1"
  "Accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
  "Referer"="http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "dnt"="1"
} `
-ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyd1R4wTBVjKkPZWW"
```

I've got a guide to how to do this [here for further reading](https://foxdeploy.com/2018/04/02/faster-web-cmdlet-design-with-chrome-65/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try it and let you know how it went.

Many thanks once again.

Comment: If this helped you, remember to vote up or mark as answer 