# SESSION_FAILURE: Your session has expired. Please try again" whenever attempting to authenticate to a Check Point device with "Invoke-WebRequest"

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I'm using this method to generate PowerShell code for posting to a webpage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62639441/7649168

Specifically, I'm trying to authenticate to a device via its webpage interface.

No problems there. It generates code that essentially looks like this after I successfully login:

```
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("cpnacportal_username", "myusername", "/", "mydevicename.mydomain.net")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_ga", "systemidentifier?", "/", ".mydomain.net")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("systemidentifier", "systemidentifier", "/", ".mydomain.net")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("MYSAPSSO2", "InsertLongHashHere", "/", "mydomain.net")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("SAPWP_active", "1", "/", ".mydomain.net")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("NACSID", "InsertHashHere", "/", "mydevicename.mydomain.net")))
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://mydevicename.mydomain.net/connect/Login" `
-Method "POST" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="*/*"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "Origin"="my"
  "Referer"="https://mydevicename.mydomain.net/connect/PortalMain"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-origin"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Not/A)Brand`";v=`"99`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"115`", `"Chromium`";v=`"115`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?1"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Android`""
} `
-ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `
-Body "realm=passwordRealm&username=myusername&password=inserthashhere"
```

However, when I try to run the same code in PowerShell, I only get "SESSION_FAILURE: Your session has expired. Please try again" in the response. (This will happen in the browser too if left up too long without logging in.)

I'm trying to decipher the mechanism by which the server makes the determination? I can get responses back with no indication of any error when I just load the page via Invoke-Webrequest. The issue only occurs when trying to POST the credentials. I note that the password hash changes with each login (even though the password itself is not being changed), but it seems unlikely to me that the session information is embedded there. Looking through the JS code, I think the "NACSID" cookie hash that is passed is just related to pop-ups, but I'm not entirely sure. That's the only other field that changes best I can tell, each time I successfully login from the browser and copy the PS code to see what the system generates.

[image]

In short, can anyone explain on how the server determines if a session has expired in a situation like this?